# Error serializing `.remarkBody` returned from `getStaticProps` . Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown, remarkjs

I'm getting this error

```
Error: Error serializing `.remarkBody` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/blog/[slug]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

when trying to run this:

```
const body = blogPostCollection ? blogPostCollection?.items[0]?.body : ''

  const remarkBody = remark().use(strip).process(body, (err, file) => {
    if (err) throw err
    String(file)
  })

  return {
    props: {
      remarkBody: remarkBody,
    },
    revalidate: 1
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe u can use this following workaround to bypass this issue:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
const remarkBody = await getPropsFromAService()

return { props: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(remarkBody)) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass `undefined` in the returned `props` from `getStaticProps`. Instead, you can try defaulting to `null` when that happens.

```js
return {
    props: {
        remarkBody: remarkBody ?? null,
    },
    revalidate: 1
}
```