# Next.js Error Serializing `results` returned from `getServerSideProps`

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, next.js

I'm working with Next.js trying to `getServerSIdeProps` and and getting this error:

> Error: Error serializing `.results` returned from `getServerSideProps`
> in "/". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use
> `null` or omit this value.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const genre = context.query.genre;

  const request = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url
    }`
  ).then((res) =>  res.json());
     
   return {
    props: {
      results: request.results,
    },
  };
}
```

It was working yesterday but today I'm getting this error. Could any body please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error serializing \`.remarkBody\` returned from \`getStaticProps\` . Reason: \`undefined\` cannot be serialized as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429899/error-serializing-remarkbody-returned-from-getstaticprops-reason-undefi)

Answer (score 0):

while converting your data to JSON an error was thrown because the value `undefined` can not be serialized in other words you can't turn objects with undefined as the value of one of their properties to json.

You need to turn the `undefined` value to `null` value for javascript to be able to serialize it to JSON(convert it to JSON).

The easiest way to turn `undefined` values to `null` in javascript is using a library called `Lodash`. Install `Lodash` using the commands below:

```
$ npm install lodash
// or
$ yarn add lodash
```

After that create the functions below:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function prepareForSerializatoin(obj) {
    return obj.mapValues(obj, value => typeof value === 'undefined' ? null : value);
}
```

Finally, use this function while returning your response:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const genre = context.query.genre;

  const request = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url
    }`
  ).then((res) =>  res.json());
     
   return prepareForSerializatoin({
    props: {
      results: request.results,
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Where should i declare this function 
function prepareForSerializatoin(obj) ...inside the component body?

Comment: @SebastianMarquez declare it somewhere else. I would do it in a separate file to use it on every `getServerSideProps` that I have.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const request = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${
      requests[genre]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url
    }`
  ).then((res) =>  res.json()) || '';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: With your solution, `request` is an empty string instead of undefined. Accessing `request.results` will still cause the same error, as there is no `results` property on an empty string.